# MySQL week numbers and New Year

Tags: mysql

The website I'm working on now has a dashboard showing data entered during the previous week by various users. I select this data using a simple WHERE clause:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE WEEK(date, 1) = WEEK(CURDATE(), 1) - 1`

However, the New Year is coming soon, and when a user tries to view the dashboard on, for example, 3rd or 4th of January, my code is clearly going to give me a wrong result, because the last week's number of 2010 is 52. So, what would be the best way to alter my query to take into account the change of the year. And also, it would be cool to make it possible to select data entered 2, 3, 4,... weeks ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about selecting the `WEEK` of the day seven days ago?

```
WHERE WEEK(date, 1) = WEEK(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK, 1)
```

This way you can select data entered 2,3,4 weeks ago:

```
WHERE WEEK(date, 1) = WEEK(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK, 1)
```

Comment: I have this written (except for the second argument which gives me error - Operand should contain 1 column(s) ), but this query gives me data for all years by given week. I would like to choose only last year, given that 3 weeks ago was year 2012 only.

Answer (score -1):

Why you can't use:

```
 WHERE date between date_add(CurDate() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and CurDate()
```

Comment: He wants 'previous week', not 'last 7 days'.