# MySQL WEEK() - do I also have to compare YEARs?

Tags: mysql

This is part of my query:

```
WHERE WEEK( data.time ) = ( WEEK( CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -3 WEEK ) )
```

I can select data from three weeks ago, that means December 2012. 
Now the problem is - I get data for that week for all years. Not just the one that has been three weeks ago.

Adding

```
YEAR( data.time ) = YEAR( CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -3 WEEK )
```

Solved the problem, but I wonder if it is necessary to compare the years also, or if I could stay with the week comparison only - if I adjust the first line somehow.

I've found similar query in here
[MySQL week numbers and New Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398381/mysql-week-numbers-and-new-year)
but they don't mention such an issue with years and it seems it works for them even without year comparison.

Comment: You are using two *different* dates in your example, `data.time` and `report.cas_zaciatok`. How are they related?

Comment: I'm sorry, they were supposed to be the same, I just copy wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be better served by comparing with the start and end of the required week. Something like:

```
WHERE SUBDATE(CURDATE(), WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 21) <= data.time 
    AND data.time < SUBDATE(CURDATE(), WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 14);
```

It *will* make a difference for the first and last week of the year. For example 2012-12-31 is part of 2013-W01 (first week of *2013*). So `WEEK` would say `1` while `YEAR` would say `2012`. Whereas for 2013-01-13, also part of 2013-W01 `WEEK` is `1` and `YEAR` is `2013`. So naïve use of `WEEK` and `YEAR` for this will give you the wrong results.

Comment: That is a good point. I knew there was something wrong with comparing years in this case :) I don't know about subdate, will try your suggestion out.

Comment: @OriesokVlassky `SUBDATE` substracts some days from a date.

Comment: +1, nice, but using `NOW()` and `BETWEEN` can cause some funny effects at the ends of the week. (The cutoff will vary depending on the time of day, and the weeks will also overlap slightly because `BETWEEN` is inclusive.) It would be better to use `date.time >= SUBDATE(CURDATE(), WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 21) AND date.time < SUBDATE(CURDATE(), WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) - 14)`.

Comment: Also, you might want to note that, if the `data.time` column is indexed, this will be significantly more efficient that using `WEEK()`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I fixed the `BETWEEN` issue…

Comment: @OriesokVlassky I fixed the sign in date calculations.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, if you have data that exists in your table across many years, then you should always include a `Year()` comparison.

Your database does not know unless you tell it that you only want 2012.

So when you write a query you would include:

```
select *
from yourtable 
where week(yourdate) = week(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -3 WEEK)
  and year(yourdate) = year(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -3 WEEK)
```

Same thing if you were comparing months:

```
select *
from yourtable 
where month(yourdate) = month(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -3 WEEK)
  and year(yourdate) = year(CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL -3 WEEK)
```

Doing this makes sure that you are returning data that matches both the week and year or month and year.